# Custom SharePoint List Form doesn't fit in screen height and width

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps-canvas

I have created a custom form for our one list using the Power app. I am facing issues related to form width and height.

As you can see in the first image my form is showing all the fields at once and show the perfect size. I only need to use Y-axis to scroll the access to the form.

But in the second image, my form got a bad view the size of the field got automatically increased.

I need to scroll both X-axis and Y-axis to access the all fields of the form.

How can I fix this issue?
I have set my form height to 850 and width to 900.
Is there a way to set the screen in the “Scale to fit” view?
Can we increase the form width to the full page view?

[image: When click on "new" or "edit" it shows perfect size form]
[image: After reloading its change the form size]
[image: Can we set the form to full page view?]

I tried to change the form size but it's after a reload all field sizes get increased automatically.